# Balancing columns, last page of index (using memoir class)

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, indexing, two-column, idxlayout

I've just received (very final, I hope) editing requests from the production people at CUP, and -- at the last minute -- they are asking for the two columns of the final page of the index of my book to be balanced.

It would be nice to be able to do this. The book is written using the `memoir` class, and the index generated by a simple `\printindex` command.

I've tried loading `idxlayout.sty` but -- even placed at the beginning of the preamble -- it gives an error message: `Command \indexcolsep already defined`.

So ...

1. Either, is there another way of getting the two columns on the final page of the index to balance?
2. Or is there a trick to getting `idxlayout` to play nicely with `memoir`?

Apologies if I've missed something I shouldn't have: but I have to return the PDF to the publisher rather snappily!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to redefine `theindex` in order to use the `multicols` environment:

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewenvironment{theindex}
 {\clearforchapter 
  \ifonecolindex
    \chapter*{\indexname}
    \preindexhook
  \else
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{\indexrule} 
    \setlength{\columnsep}{\indexcolsep} 
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}\preindexhook] 
  \fi
  \indexmark
  \ifnoindexintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{indextitlepagestyle}\parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
  \let\item\@idxitem} 
 {\ifonecolindex\else\end{multicols}\fi}
\makeatother
```

This assuming that your book is not in twocolumn format.

Comment: This works to balance the index, thanks. But (oddly?) where `{\small\printindex}` got the index printed at a smaller size, this no longer works. (And font size is more critical than balanced columns here!)

Comment: @PeterSmith Maybe it's better to add `\small` just at the end of the first part of the definition: `\let\item\@idxitem\small`

Comment: This does this trick nicely. Thanks so very much! [If others want to use this, you might find that you have to tinker with the settings of the pre-index text called by `\preindexhook` to get it to set as raw memoir did.]

Comment: @PeterSmith That's also an option; but since you're redefining `theindex` anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use lockstep's `idxlayout` package (which is compatible with `memoir`). It balances the index columns by default, and also features a `font` option. Allowed values are `normalsize`, `small`, `footnotesize`, and `current` (the font in effect at the time of `\printindex`).

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP: The following example works for me:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

Some text.\index{Alpha}\index{Bravo}\index{Charlie}\index{Delta}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]